# How to get a reference to a DOM element that depends on an input parameter?

Tags: reactjs

Say I have the standard TODO app, and want a ref to the last item in the list. I might have something like:

```
const TODO = ({items}) => {
  const lastItemRef = Reeact.useRef()
  return {
    <>
      {items.map(item => <Item ref={item == items.last() ? lastItemRef : undefined} />)}
    <>
  }
}
```

But this doesn't seem to work - after `lastItemRef` is initialized, it is never subsequently updated as items are added to `items`. Is there a clean way of doing this without using a selector?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think in your case it depends upon how the items list is updated. This is because [useRef](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useref) won't re-render the component if you change its `current` attribute (persistent). But it does re-render when you choose, for example, [useState](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usestate).

Just as a [working case](https://codesandbox.io/s/tender-frog-9v01k?file=/src/App.js), see if this is what you were looking for.

Ps: check the console

Comment: No in this case, I want the ref to point to the last in a list. The list itself is normal `useState` and updates call the corresponding setter, but the ref doesn't seem to update after an item is added to the list (which should yield a different DOM element being referred to)

Comment: I think I put the wrong link. Check if it you can see something now (using list of hour:minute)

Comment: Ah yes that works! It seems my actual problem was something different, and it looked like the problem was a ref problem. Thanks for the really concise explanation & example :)